# Diagnosing Bluetooth app interaction (interfering with Bluetooth audio playback)

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-bluetooth

I have an iOS Bluetooth app that acts as a CBCentral and connects to another acting as a CBPeripheral. The Central requests notification for connect/disconnect of the Peripheral and notifies if the connection is lost so you know if the peripheral has gone out of range like Tile and some other Bluetooth locator gadgets do.

The application is generally working as intended, but I noticed that when it is running that audio played over Bluetooth to my car stereo is interrupted. It cuts in and out rhythmically like a record skipping. It happens with multiple Bluetooth playback apps (Music and Downcast). I thought maybe it was the new OS or my new iPhone 6, but when I killed my application the symptom disappeared.

How do you go about testing and diagnosing this sort of interference? Instruments reveals that the Bluetooth system is on, but not much else. It doesn't report back when the app is suspended. I see some small amount of Audio Processing going on that I'm going to investigate. Otherwise the app is pretty quiescent in the background.

Here are the things my app is currently doing:

On one iOS device, it acts as a peripheral and advertises a service:

```
[self.peripheralManager startAdvertising:@{ CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey: @[kServiceUUID], CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey: @"MyIdentifier"}];
```

When the Central runs, he looks for devices advertising this characteristic, connects and requests notifications (not actually subscribing to the characteristic):

```
- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService:(CBService *)service error:(NSError *)error {
    if (error) {
        [self cleanup];
        return;
    }

    for (CBCharacteristic *characteristic in service.characteristics) {
        if ([characteristic.UUID isEqual:kSlaveDeviceUUID]) {
            [peripheral setNotifyValue:YES forCharacteristic:characteristic];
        }
    }
}
```

I get the appropriate response for the `didUpdateNotificationStateForCharacteristic` callback, etc.

I can turn off bluetooth on the peripheral and get notified that it is gone, turn it back on and get a reconnect, take the device out of range and back and get notifications, both in the foreground and background.

This seems like pretty vanilla stuff, but I a must be missing something important.

Comment: Is the audio skipping on the central or peripheral?  Are you actually exchanging data or are you just using the characteristic notifications as a "keep alive"?

Comment: The iPhone is acting as Central. I am not exchanging any data, only using the notifications as keep alive.

Comment: Then all you need to do is make a connection and if the device goes out of range you will get a call to `didDisconnectPeripheral`.  There shouldn't be any need to actually exchange data.

Comment: Yep. I connect to the peripheral and it is all working as planned. I'm trying to understand why this would interfere with Bluetooth playback and see if anyone has techniques for diagnosing it.

Comment: Do you get the interference if you don't activate the notifications?

Comment: The devices are in close proximity inside the car, so no notifications are being raised. I would expect no Bluetooth activity at all until they fall out of range and a disconnect or reconnect occurs.